# javascript - schedule with tabs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, twitter-bootstrap, schedule

I created I javascript schedule thermostat for a enteire week and work. But now I have some problems with tabs, because when I move a period, moving on slider, I have graphics problem.

I add the code on jsfiddle, because so it's more simple to understand and see the code working.

Here have a code HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="pill" href="#tabs-1">Zone 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="pill" href="#tabs-2">Zone 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="pill" href="#tabs-3">Zone 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="pill" href="#tabs-4">Zone 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tabs-1">
            <div class="slider-label">Mon</div>
            <div class="slider" day="mon" zone="1"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Tue</div>
            <div class="slider" day="tue" zone="1"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Wed</div>
            <div class="slider" day="wed" zone="1"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Thu</div>
            <div class="slider" day="thu" zone="1"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Fri</div>
            <div class="slider" day="fri" zone="1"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Sat</div>
            <div class="slider" day="sat" zone="1"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Sun</div>
            <div class="slider" day="sun" zone="1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tabs-2">
            <div class="slider-label">Mon</div>
            <div class="slider" day="mon" zone="2"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Tue</div>
            <div class="slider" day="tue" zone="2"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Wed</div>
            <div class="slider" day="wed" zone="2"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Thu</div>
            <div class="slider" day="thu" zone="2"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Fri</div>
            <div class="slider" day="fri" zone="2"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Sat</div>
            <div class="slider" day="sat" zone="2"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Sun</div>
            <div class="slider" day="sun" zone="2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tabs-3">
            <div class="slider-label">Mon</div>
            <div class="slider" day="mon" zone="3"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Tue</div>
            <div class="slider" day="tue" zone="3"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Wed</div>
            <div class="slider" day="wed" zone="3"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Thu</div>
            <div class="slider" day="thu" zone="3"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Fri</div>
            <div class="slider" day="fri" zone="3"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Sat</div>
            <div class="slider" day="sat" zone="3"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Sun</div>
            <div class="slider" day="sun" zone="3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tabs-4">
            <div class="slider-label">Mon</div>
            <div class="slider" day="mon" zone="4"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Tue</div>
            <div class="slider" day="tue" zone="4"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Wed</div>
            <div class="slider" day="wed" zone="4"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Thu</div>
            <div class="slider" day="thu" zone="4"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Fri</div>
            <div class="slider" day="fri" zone="4"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Sat</div>
            <div class="slider" day="sat" zone="4"></div>
            <div class="slider-label">Sun</div>
            <div class="slider" day="sun" zone="4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code complete with also javascript is present on jsfiddle.

Thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/k25nbbrp/

**screenshot** 
[image]

Comment: It's a bit complicated to help you. You should use console.log to print value and the code inspector to see what cause the wrong behaviour. Good luck with this.

Comment: "I have graphics problem". That's a very vague description. What goes wrong exactly? Does it happen in all browsers? I've just opened your fiddle using Chrome and played about with the sliders, but there's no obvious issue.

Comment: The problem have when you move slider, when you get on seperation period and move. The left and width size of slider have problems. You can see this problem?

Comment: I add an image for demostrate bug. This bug I have only with tab when I add the tag zone= on slider_update_ui. When I move the slider I have this bug!

Comment: absolutely don't understand what your issue is. The image shows the issue, but your fiddle cannot reproduce that easily. You should add a detailed step-by-step guide on how to reproduce the issue with your jsfiddle. I can see that your English is not very good, so spend some time writing it carefully (with other assitant tools like Google translate, ...).

Comment: By using your JSFiddle I cannot produce the gap between the items, as shown in your image. Please provide detailed steps which explain how to make the error happen.

Comment: Yes my english is not good. The issue you can see on second tab and other. On first seems to be ok, but on others tab not. You can you move on vertical line of separation on slider beetween different colors for move and try on all days for reproduce the issue.

Comment: that does not happen when I move the sliders. Is the problem restricted to a specific browser version, maybe?

Comment: I try again and I have the issue. Try with other tabs on all days. On monday on tab 3 I have the issue, but after try on tab 1 and tab 2. It's variable, not always this issue repcoduce at same moment. Yesterday I try on Firefox and Chrome, and on both reproduce the issue. Thank you

Comment: I've just noticed that your code is throwing lots of errors about undefined variables. That could be a possible source of your problem. Check your browser console and fix those errors.

Comment: But when you have see this errors of undefined variables? You have used an console.log for see this or with other tools? Thank you

Comment: just by watching the console. It happens in the JSFiddle whenever you move the slider.